# Simulate Active Directory Remote Site

Tags: active-directory

Any guide on setting up two domain controllers  (DC1 Primary Site different network segment and DC2-Remote Site different network segment) - in the same Active Directory domain.
just for simulation purposes.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create two Hyper-V private virtual switches. Then create two virtual machines, one connected to each virtual switch. Assign both virtual machines an ip address configuration in two different subnets. Create a third virtual machine and connect it to both virtual switches with an appropriate ip address configuration for each subnet. Configure the third virtual machine as a router (pfsense or RRAS) so that it can route traffic between the two virtual machines. Configure the two virtual machines to use the appropriate ip address of the third virtual machine as their Default Gateway. Install whatever roles, services and applications on the two virtual machines to allow you to perform your testing.